# Hypersurfaces with Picard group generated by classes of lines on the same plane

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, picard-group

For which values of $d$ is the following possible: There exist a smooth hypersurface $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$ of degree $d$ with Picard number $d$, containing $d-1$ lines $l_1,...,l_{d-1}$ on the same plane  such that the Neron-Severi group of $X$ is generated by the ample line bundle and the classes of these $d-1$ lines $l_i$?

Comment: Please explain what cases you know, allude to why you might care, what your expectation may be and why, etc. Questions asked in this fashion do not generally receive good responses.

Comment: What's the base field?  Is it algebraically closed?

Comment: @Bright: The base field in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Huizenga: The motivation comes from the study of Noether-Lefschetz locus which I unfortunately do not think is possible to explain in a paragraph. I am sorry. I would expect that for $d$ large enough this phenomenon happens. Again this is motivated by results on Noether-Lefschetz locus.